# How to round a decimal to the next nearest "10s"?

Tags: apex

I have a decimal value 61.31.
I would like to know if it is possible to round it to the next (not neccessarily the nearest) "10s" which is 61.40

Something like

```
1.07 => 1.10

1.11 => 1.20

61.31 => 61.40
```

I did some research and I can see `setscale()` in `Decimal` class but I need the value to the next nearest 10s.

Is it possible to do that in apex ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`setScale()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_decimal.htm) method with `RoundingMode.UP` or `RoundingMode.CEILING` depending on your preferred behavior with negative numbers. (`UP` rounds away from zero, `CEILING` towards positive infinity).

```
Decimal d = 61.31;
d = d.setScale(1, RoundingMode.UP);
```

> 21:39:19:002 USER_DEBUG [3]|DEBUG|61.4

If you need the second decimal place, just do another `setScale(2)`:

```
Decimal d = 61.31;
d = d.setScale(1, RoundingMode.UP);
System.debug(d.setScale(2));
```

> 21:41:33:002 USER_DEBUG [3]|DEBUG|61.40